# error: missing } in xml expression for exeternal javascript?

Tags: javascript

I write external js and write JSON string in js file want to parse main html file's js tag but it gives like

`**error: missing } in xml expression**`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I miss out the sequence of loading external style and script file, that's why that error occur I am using jqtouch and jquery's functionality in external js and where actually the problem comes into the picture.
so I added here the correct sequence for loading script-

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">@import "jqtouch/jqtouch.min.css";</style>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">@import "jqtouch/themes/theme.css";</style>

<script src="jqtouch/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="jqtouch/jqtouch.min.js" type="application/x-javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="Common.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="LoginLiveInterface.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
```

Answer (score 1):

doublecheck that your JSON uses quotes, e.g. `{a:"b", ...` is invalid, you must use `{"a":"b", ...`

Answer (score 0):

Look through your code carefully, make sure you didn't forget a closing bracket, brace or semicolon somewhere in your code.

If you want people to get a better idea of what is wrong, you should post your code.